# Is it possible to wipe the phone without uninstalling the apps?

Tags: applications, factory-reset, google-account

I'm having problems with my Google account in my phone and because of that I want to remove it and add it again. When I try to do it, it tells me that I can't remove it unless I restore to factory defaults. But I don't want to reinstall every app. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are rooted, you can use an app like [Titanium Backup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) to back up your apps (and their data).